# O que siginifca "not CLS-compliant" no C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou portando um código para C#, mas tenho notado que várias funções possuem um aviso de ""not CLS-compliant", por exemplo:

> Important
>
> This API is not CLS-compliant.

Um exemplo disso, pode ser visto em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=net-6.0#system-text-encoding-getbytes(system-char*-system-int32-system-byte*-system-int32):

```
[System.CLSCompliant(false)]
public virtual int GetBytes (char* chars, int charCount, byte* bytes, int byteCount);
```

Inclusive, a própria função tem essa "atributo" de `System.CLSCompliant`. Mas, o que isso significa e porque há este aviso de forma tão evidente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor resposta do meu ponto de vista é:

> Se você está escrevendo uma biblioteca ou framework, faz sentido que
> seu código possa ser usado por qualquer Especificação de linguagem
> comum (CLS sigla em inglês).
>
> A conformidade com CLS é particularmente importante se você estiver
> distribuindo bibliotecas - especificamente, escrever em conformidade
> com CLS garante que suas bibliotecas possam ser usadas por todas as
> linguagens compatíveis com CLS.
>
> Por exemplo, o Visual Basic não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas
> (case sensitive), enquanto o C# sim. Um dos requisitos de conformidade
> com CLS é que os nomes de membros públicos (e protegidos) não devem
> diferir apenas por caso, garantindo assim que suas bibliotecas possam
> ser usadas com segurança pelo código Visual Basic ou qualquer outra
> linguagem .NET que não diferencie com base em caso.

`Nota: Esta resposta é na verdade uma tradução de duas respostas para uma questão idêntica em outro tópico no stackoverflow em inglês. Deixarei a referência abaixo:`

[Por que devo escrever código compatível com CLS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828575/why-should-i-write-cls-compliant-code)